# Trying to get google map with user set radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, slider

I am tring to allow the user to set the radius from the users center location of a google map. I have most of the nuts and bolts but can't get it over the line. Here is the code I'm using. Any help is much appreciated.

css AND html code

```
Search Radius:
    <input type="range" name="search_radius" id="search_radius" min="10" max="100">
    <script>
        // Add a Circle overlay to the map.
        circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: 10
        });

        // Since Circle and Marker both extend MVCObject, you can bind them
        // together using MVCObject's bindTo() method.  Here, we're binding
        // the Circle's center to the Marker's position.
        // http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MVCObject
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
        }


        $("#search_radius").slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            max: 3000,
             min: 100,
            value: 500,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                updateRadius(circle, ui.value);
            }
        });

        function updateRadius(circle, rad) {
            circle.setRadius(rad);
        }

        // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

    </script



<center>
    <script>getLocation();</script>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Get My Location</button><p id="map"></p>

    Search Radius:
    <input type="range" name="search_radius" id="search_radius" min="10" max="100">
    <script>
        // Add a Circle overlay to the map.
        circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: 10
        });

        // Since Circle and Marker both extend MVCObject, you can bind them
        // together using MVCObject's bindTo() method.  Here, we're binding
        // the Circle's center to the Marker's position.
        // http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MVCObject
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
        }


        $("#search_radius").slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            max: 3000,
             min: 100,
            value: 500,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                updateRadius(circle, ui.value);
            }
        });

        function updateRadius(circle, rad) {
            circle.setRadius(rad);
        }

        // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

    </script

<!--Check Geolocation Support -->
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("map");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
     var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude},
      zoom: 12
    });
}

function initMap() {
     var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: {lat: 53.3498, lng: -6.2603},
      zoom: 6
    });

  }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: I do use initMap which should be unnecessary as the user has to Click Get Location.  This is'nt the right approach but I can't think of a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating the map after the circle's radius is changed. I haven't tested the code below.

```
function updateRadius(circle, rad) {
  circle.setRadius(rad);
  map.fitBounds(circle.getBounds());
}
```

Documentation on map.fitBounds is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

You should also probably just have one map object that in a scope that is accessible by all your functions and just set the center and zoom options on it instead of creating a new map object for the different options. I also don't see in the current code how the map object is accessible to the first script code that adds the circle.

```
var x = document.getElementById("map");
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
  center: {lat: 53.3498, lng: -6.2603},
  zoom: 6
});

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

    map.center = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng:     position.coords.longitude};
    map.zoom = 12;
  });
}
```