# Google Maps JS API - extend a circle

Tags: javascript, maps, geometry, geo

The User is allowed to draw a circle on the map, and then you can add markers - if the Marker is outside of the circle, then the circle should be enlarged to take the marker inside.

I could not find anything in the documentation:

Is there a possibility like: `UserCircle.extend(event.overlay.location);`
While event overlay is the marker.

I also tried to make this function on my own - but I get stuck on the radius.
Which unit is it? How can I convert it into degrees?

Any Ideas?

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997093/trying-to-get-google-map-with-user-set-radius

Answer (score 0):

Thats what i made now...

```
function extendRegion(marker, drawing){
    marker_lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
    marker_lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
    if(drawing.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE){
        var path = [marker.getPosition(), drawing.overlay.getCenter()];
        var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(path[0], path[1]);

        if(length>drawing.overlay.getRadius()){
            consloe.log('The Marker was outside the drawing, it is extended now.');
            drawing.overlay.setRadius(length);
        }
    }
    else if(drawing.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE){
        ne_lat = drawing.overlay.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
        ne_lng = drawing.overlay.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
        sw_lat = drawing.overlay.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
        sw_lng = drawing.overlay.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();

        var error=0;
        if(marker_lat<sw_lat){
            sw_lat = marker_lat;
            error=1;
        }
        if(marker_lat>ne_lat){
            ne_lat = marker_lat;
            error=1;
        }
        if(marker_lng<sw_lng){
            sw_lng = marker_lng;
            error=1;
        }
        if(marker_lng>ne_lng){
            ne_lng = marker_lng;
            error=1;
        }

        if(error) {
            console.log('The Marker was outside the drawing, it is extended now.');
            drawing.overlay.setBounds({north: ne_lat, south: sw_lat, east: ne_lng, west: sw_lng});
        }
    }
}
```